# Getting null output with both >> and getline even i'm using string whitespaces

Tags: c++, string, getline

I'm trying to add variables by users input using >> or getline but it is giving null values with both of them .As we know `getline` does not ignore leading whitespace characters that's why i'm using string whitespaces like `employeeName=" ";` `string designation=" ";`.
Can anyone help me for getting proper output

```
class Employee{
  public:
  int employeeId,salary;
  string employeeName=" ";
  string designation=" ";
  void getEmployee(){
    cin>>employeeId;
    getline(cin,employeeName);
    getline(cin,designation);
    cin>>salary;
  }
  void ShowEmployee(){
    cout<<"Employee Id="<<employeeId<<"\n";
    cout<<"Employee Name="<<employeeName<<"\n";
    cout<<"Designation="<<designation<<"\n";
    cout<<"Salary="<<salary<<"\n";
  }
};
int main() {
  Employee ob;
  ob.getEmployee();
  ob.ShowEmployee();
}
```

[image]
can anyone help me :)

Comment: Voting to close as typo. You forgot to ever call `getEmployee()` and you didn't actuall put the variables to output in your `cout<<` statements (except for `salary`).

Comment: And in anticipation of the next problem, please read [c++ getline() isn't waiting for input from console when called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).

Comment: Sorry i forget those things ,please check the edited code and please help me getting proper output.

Comment: It would help if you could also post your input text.

Comment: yes i had uploaded ,please check it

Answer (score 1):

But you are not calling getEmployee in your example. Did you forget?

You can also try a constructor passing the std::istream& to it like

```
Employee(std::istream& in) {
  in >> this->employeeId;
  in >> this->salary;
  ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forget to call getEmployee here , I also tried this using 'this' constructor but it is giving same null values .Please check the edited code and help me.

Comment: Not a problem.  For a very quick and very dirty approach you can go with a cin.ignore(); before your first std::geline(...) that will allow to enter lines terminated with a NL.

Comment: As @Kaldrr pointed before, it would be better not to mix the operator >> and getlline()
It looks like you can read all the information to std::string using getline and convert those that need to be numbers instead. For instance using this approach [std:stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/)

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling the `getEmployee` member functions.
As your `Employee` object is created on the stack, and `employeeId` and `salary` are not initialized, they contain garbage values inside them.

In the `ShowEmployee` member function you're only outputting the `salary` variable value, so I'm guessing this isn't exactly the code that you're compiling and testing for yourself.

As for your reasoning why you're using `getline`, I don't understand it at all, the string that's passed as the 2nd argument will be overwritten, so whatever was in it before the call is lost. But if you want to mix `operator>>` and `getline` calls on the same stream like you do, you need to use  [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), as `operator>>` won't extract `'\n'` from the stream, which will be read by `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

```
getline(cin,employeeName);
getline(cin,designation);
```

In the code above you are overwriting the string,If you want to mix users input of multiple datatypes try to use `cin.ignore;` before your first std::getline(...).